# How to speeding up CGAL Triangulation Algorithms with Parallelization

Tags: c++, cgal

I am currently working on a project that involves performing Delaunay Triangulation, Constrained Delaunay Triangulation, and Alpha Shape calculations using CGAL. The size of my input data can be quite large, and these computations can take a significant amount of time to complete. I have heard that CGAL supports parallelization to take advantage of multi-core processors and potentially speed up these computations.

I would like to enable parallelization in CGAL to improve the performance of these triangulation algorithms. Specifically, I want to speed up the following operations:

1. 2D Delaunay Triangulation
2. 2D Constrained Delaunay Triangulation
3. 2D Alpha Shape Calculation

Could someone please guide me on **how to enable** and use parallelization in CGAL for these triangulation algorithms? I am using CGAL version 5.5.2.

Any code examples or step-by-step instructions on how to modify my existing code to make use of parallelization would be highly appreciated.

## Edit

Here is my code for the 2D Alpha Shape calculation for about 40 million points. It takes 11+ minutes! That doesn't meet my requirements. Am I using the API incorrectly?

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel EPIC;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_2<EPIC> AlphaShapeVertexBase;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_face_base_2<EPIC> AlphaShapeFaceBase;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<AlphaShapeVertexBase, AlphaShapeFaceBase> AlphaShapeTDS;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<EPIC, AlphaShapeTDS> AlphaShapeDelaunayTriangulation;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_2<AlphaShapeDelaunayTriangulation, CGAL::Tag_false> Alpha_shape_2;
typedef EPIC::Point_2 Point_2;
            
std::vector<Point_2> points;
points.reserve(numPoints);
const size_t pointDimension = 3;
for (size_t pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < numPoints; ++pointIndex) {
    const size_t offset = pointIndex * pointDimension;
    const size_t xCoordinateIndex = offset;
    const size_t yCoordinateIndex = offset + 1;
    points.push_back(Point_2(pPoints[xCoordinateIndex], pPoints[yCoordinateIndex]));
}

const double maxTriangleEdgeLength = 50;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
const Alpha_shape_2 alphaShape(points.begin(), points.end(), maxTriangleEdgeLength, Alpha_shape_2::REGULARIZED);
auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(stop - start);
```

```
2D Alpha Shape calculation for 39651210 points took: 11 min.
```

Comment: IIRC, only the 3D triangulation has been parallelized in CGAL, in part because 2D is usually fast enough.

Comment: If you shared your code we might have a look if you use the API optimally.

Comment: @AndreasFabri I shared my code in the question above.

Comment: @MarcGlisse For me it's too slow.

Comment: The triangulation part (what is parallelized in 3d) might be fast enough, it is the computation of alpha values that is slow. A priori it should be possible to parallelize, but since the current code seems to spend all its time in multimap operations, I am not sure it would be easy.